# Jquery: Insert an element in a HTML string?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML string

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">      
    content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    contnt
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">      
    content
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert

```
<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>
```

at the end of the second row (before the closing div tag) so that the second row has three elements.

I tried many things using Jquery for the task, but I am unable to do it. The latest I tried is the following (suppose the long html is stored in HTML, and the to-be-inserted PIECE.

```
$(HTML).find('.col-sm-4').last().after(PIECE);
```

Can anyone help me out? There must be a JQuery way for this.

**UPDATE**: one more thing I forgot to say:

The number of rows is not fixed. I want the PIECE to be inserted into the last row. **Note that the long HTML string is NOT part of a page. It is just a string stored in a Javascript variable**. I need to insert

```
class="col-sm-4">content</div>
```

into it. In my many tests, I find that it is pretty difficult to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is unclear, do you have an html string or html content?

Comment: HTML string, not DOM (part of a page) I need to insert <div class="col-sm-4">content</div> into  the string. Sorry that I am not clear enough.

Comment: I believe jQuery works on the DOM. If you want string manipulation, you might just try a regex replace. Not sure. Or just replace the last </div> with your new content.

Comment: B2K, thanks for your input. I did string replacement in Javascript before my post. I feel there must be a JQuery solution on this. Maybe I am wrong. I tried many ways, to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$('.row:last').append(PIECE);
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tu935/ it does work.

```
HTML.replace(/<\/div>$/,PIECE+'</div');
```

Comment: B2K, thanks for your new way of handling this. The HTML should not be added to the page before adding the inserted content. I feel I can hide it before showing, and then add the inserted content, etc...I feel this is really too much. Javascript string replace is a lot easier. But I feel there must be an elegant JQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks for the string replacement solution, which is what I did before my post. I am really surprised that no JQuery solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.row').eq(1).find(':last').after('<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N77fs/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can do:

```
$('.row').last().find(':last').after('<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to say this: The number of rows is not fixed.

Comment: So you want to add third element to those rows with class `row` which only have two elements?

Comment: Felix, I want the PIECE get inserted into the last row. The last row always has two elements there.

Comment: Did you miss the long HTML? I tried it, not working.  Here is waht have: $(HTML).find('.row').last().find(':last').after('<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>');

Comment: Most important, it should work on a HTML string, not on DOM. I tried. It is NOT working on the HTML string, but working on DOM.

Comment: What is `$(HTML)` here?

Comment: HTML is the original long HTML string (NOT part of a page). I need to insert that <div class="col-sm-4">content</div> into it.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an ID to the row you want to add the child to like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="test">content</div>
```

Then add this to javascript:

```
$('#test').find(':last').after('<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>');
OR
$('#test').append('<div class="col-sm-4">content</div>');
```

And try to use span inside divs if possible

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I cannot modify the long HTML. It is passed from another place.